# PayPal SDK INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR

Tags: java, android-studio, paypal, internal-server-error

I need to integrate PayPal payment in my mobile app. But this error occur

I am using this PayPal Android SDK version

```
implementation 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0'
```

I start service

```
        //Paypal Service
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    startService(intent);
```

Then I make payment

```
        amount = edtAmount.getText().toString();
    PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount)), "USD", "Pay Now",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
    startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I already did try both sandbox and production but still encounter the same problem
This is the error after i login the buyer account.

```
    E/paypal.sdk: request failure with http statusCode:404,exception:Not Found
E/paypal.sdk: Exception parsing server response
    org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
        at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:460)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:101)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cw.m(Unknown Source:7)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.fm.d(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.ci.a(Unknown Source:21)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cm.a(Unknown Source:58)
        at com.paypal.android.sdk.cq.onResponse(Unknown Source:45)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/paypal.sdk: request failed with server response:
E/paypal.sdk: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Comment: The API [seems to have been deprecated](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK#readme).

Comment: Does it mean that I can't use this to my project? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [PayPal-Android-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) is very old and end of life, use the new [Native Checkout SDK for Android](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/) instead.